# Android Clean Architecture

Tags: android, архитектура

Я разрабатываю Android приложение для взаимодействия с устройствами по MQTT
и пытаюсь написать архитектуру на Clean Architecture.
И у меня получилась следующая архитектура.

View model

```
class DevicePropertiesViewModel (application: Application, device: Device) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    var deviceLiveData = MutableLiveData<DeviceEntity>()
    val propertiesLiveData = mutableListOf<PropertyLiveData>()

    init {
        deviceLiveData.postValue(DeviceEntity(device))
        deviceLiveData.value?.connect(application, "client_id")?.subscribe {

        }

        device.properties.forEach {
            propertiesLiveData.add(PropertyLiveData(it))
        }
    }
}
```

Entity

```
class DeviceEntity(val device: Device) {

    val interactor: DeviceInteractor = MqttDeviceInteractor()

    fun connect(context: Context, clientId: String): Observable<Device> {
        return interactor.connect(clientId, device, context)
    }

    fun publish(property: Property, message: DeviceMessage) : Observable<MessageResource>  {
        return interactor.publish(device, property, message).map { MessageResource(device, property, message) }
    }

    fun messages(property: Property) : Observable<MessageResource> {
        return interactor.messages(device, property).map { MessageResource(device, property, it) }
    }

}
```

Interactor

```
interface DeviceInteractor {

    fun connect(clientId: String, device: Device, context: Context) : Observable<Device>

    fun publish(device: Device, property: Property, message: DeviceMessage) : Observable<Boolean>

    fun messages(device: Device, property: Property) : Observable<DeviceMessage>

}
```

В моем понимании Entity это сущность, реализующая логику устройства с которым можно общаться, а низкоуровневая реализация общения ложится на Interactor, а ViewModel использует Entity.

Но я нащел вот этот проект (https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture), в котором все реализовано
совершенно по-другому.

1) С чем в итоге должен общаться ViewModel с Interactor или Entity?

2) Должен ли Entity реализовывать бизнес логику

3) Может ли кто-нибудь предоставить пример, описывающий поток управления от UI к Entity

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь эту статью вы не пропустили https://habr.com/company/mobileup/blog/335382/

> 1) С чем в итоге должен общаться ViewModel с Interactor или Entity?

С Interactor.

> 2) Должен ли Entity реализовывать бизнес логику

А зачем оно тогда надо?)) Я думаю о entity так - это то, что можно взять, вынести в отдельный модуль и использовать в других приложениях как библиотеку.  Оно не знает о нашем приложении ровным счётом ничего. Оно не зависит ни отчего связаного с нашим приложением и благодаря этому нам не надо менять бизнес правила при, тут я уже утрирую, смене цвета кнопки. Entity получает данные на вход от интерактора, что то с ними делает и возвращает результат интерактору.   Уже интерактор решает как и куда их сохранять, какие системные службы вызывать, что там презентора/viewmodel попросить сделать и такое прочее.

> 3) Может ли кто-нибудь предоставить пример, описывающий поток управления от UI к Entity

Вот схема из приведенной выше статьи:

[image]